# What SAS adapter is compatible with Supermicro X9DRD-iF motherboard?

Tags: sas, supermicro, adapter

Here is my motherboard https://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Xeon/C600/X9DRD-iF.cfm

I need a compatible adapter so I can connect 2 SAS drives to this motherboard as it does not have native compatibility. Apparently Supermicro makes their own adapters, but I could not find adapters for X9.. but only for X10.. and X11.. motherboards https://www.supermicro.com/en/products/storage/cards

What SAS adapter is compatible with Supermicro X9DRD-iF motherboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your motherboard is EOL/unsupported, which naturally means the manufacturer won't be including it in current compatibility lists.

Chances are if you can find an archived compatibility list from when it was supported, there will be a certain overlap between currently supported SAS controllers and your motherboard. The usual caveats apply: Firmware does make a difference, and by choosing to run unsupported hardware in a business setting you are to some degree risking the data and/or uptime of your employer's systems.